# How to improve switch statement or replace it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the switch, it looks so long:

```
switch (+f.level) {
  case 10:
    this.region = f
    break

  case 20:
    this.aregion = f
    break

  case 30:
    this.district = f
    break

  case 40:
    this.city = f
    break

  case 50:
    this.intraCityTerritoryn = f
    break
}
```

I have tried to modify it:

```
public directory = {
  {10: this.region}, 
  {20: this.aregion}, 
  {30: this.district}, 
  {40: this.city}
};
```

Then I have tried to get varaible by key and assign `f`.

Comment: What's the problem exactly

Comment: I dislike this way with switch, because I have over 50 cases

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish exactly

Comment: Why you dont read my question, I have posted what I tried

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an lookup object with the key-value pairs of `f.level` (number value) and expected object's property

```js
const lookup = {
  10: "region",
  20: "aregion",
  30: "district",
  40: "city",
  50: "intraCityTerritoryn",
}

this[lookup[+f.level]] = f
```

For `default` equivalent case (because `this[undefined] = f` is still a valid assignment expression)

```
if (lookup[+f.level] !== undefined) {
  this[lookup[+f.level]] = f
} else {
  // ...
}
```

---

#### Reference:

- [Object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

  ```
  object.property
  object['property']
  ```

Comment: @Mamkad For example if `lookup[60]` returns `undefined` so `this` will set it property `'undefined'` to `f`. To say, every not-existed `+f.level` in lookup object will fall to `this`'s `'undefined'` property. To strictly handle this, you could do a `if` statement  `if (lookup[+f.level] !== undefined) { ... }`

Comment: What if only wrap it in try/catch?

Comment: @Mamkad it won't jump into `catch` because `this[undefined] = f` is still valid

Comment: Why it does not wotk for me:https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiEBrArgBxgXhgbwFAwwCMADAFwwBEATgKYDmAluJQDQEwBM5VAhnUxbtCAZh6UAJo2jVGwKGw4AWccEZQAnosIBWcYzBRqvAMLqNAFVrVZUENQ1hFAXxi8IbsBoDceP3jhaWAAzLFxAgDdaOApuVhgwXgBbWgpKWgzKZ188Iw1cPAj+NwFmMF8oAAtpAG0EZHQa4IA6SOiAXXaw4L9XYF4oYEqYAApaAEoCwkJQSBBA1pB6MfHfaZhZiHnaReX61DRVvGcgA

Comment: @Mamkad Because `this` in your playground is undefined so you couldn't set prop to it, for this example, just use a empty object for demo ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiEBrArgBxgXhgbwFAwwCMADAFwwBEATgKYDmAluJQDQEwBM5VAhnUxbtCAZh6UAJo2jVGwKGw4AWccEZQAnosIBWcYzBRqvAMLqNAFVrVZUENQ1hFAXxi8IbsBoDcePHFpYADMsXACAN1o4Cm5WGDBeAFtaCkpadMpnXwDYWgAPJLQA0JxnPyMNXA58woCAbQRkdDqggDoIqIBdTtCgvFdgXihgAAsYAApaAEoqwkJQSBAA9pB6SanfOZgFiCXaFbXG1DQN-qA))

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to work for you

```
const lookup = {
  10: "region",
  20: "aregion",
  30: "district",
  40: "city",
  50: "intraCityTerritoryn",
} as any;



let f = {level: 20, name: "eee"};

try {

lookup[f.level] = f
console.log(lookup);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("err: ", lookup);
}
```